# How to analyze a step response in Octave/Matlab control package

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to analyze the step response of following transfer function.
But 'dimensions mismatch' occurs in Octave when step(sys) is executed.

Is it theoretically impossible to solve the problem? The transfer function 'sys' was calculated from some circuit equations by maxima (Computer Algebra System).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
octave:2> sys
Transfer function 'sys' from input 'u1' to output ...

                 -10 s - 1e+06            
 y1:  ------------------------------------
      8.6e-17 s^3 + 0.086 s^2 + 8600 s + 1
Continuous-time model.

octave:3> step(sys, 10)
error: __step_response__: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
error: called from:
error:   /home/yusuke/octave/control-2.6.5/__time_response__.m at line 280, column 18
error:   /home/yusuke/octave/control-2.6.5/__time_response__.m at line 126, column 12
error:   /home/yusuke/octave/control-2.6.5/step.m at line 89, column 10
```

**NOTE**

Control package itself works fine as follows.

```
octave:15> sys2=tf([1],[1 1]);
octave:16> step(sys2, 10);
--> the waveform of step response is visualized successfully.
```

**Software version**

OS: Ubuntu14.04LTS

octave: 3.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me in Octave 3.8.0 on Windows but the step response is zero:

```
>> sys = tf([-10 -1e6],[8.6e-17 0.086 8600 1])

Transfer function 'sys' from input 'u1' to output ...

                 -10 s - 1e+006
 y1:  -------------------------------------
      8.6e-017 s^3 + 0.086 s^2 + 8600 s + 1

>> step(sys,10)
```

[image]

I think the reason for this is your `s^3` coefficient in the denominator is essentially zero:

```
>> sys1 = minreal(sys)

Transfer function 'sys1' from input 'u1' to output ...

              -1.163e+017
 y1:  ---------------------------
      s^2 + 1e+015 s + 1.163e+011

Continuous-time model.
>> step(sys1,10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. the second graph you attached seems to be what I expected.Thanks a lot.